# how do you find the distance between 2 points with known distances between other points

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems

link to diagram for explanation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnUMY.png

[image]

I am trying to determine the distance between i and j.

These nodes are all placed in a coordinate system.

things I know:

- coordinates of i, p and q.
- distance ip.
- distance iq.
- distance pq.
- distance pj.
- distance qj.

Does anybody know a way of doing this?
Thanks

Comment: If you know the coordinates of $i,p,q$, you don't need to explicitly state that you know the distances $ip, iq,pq$. More importantly, though, are you working in two dimensions or more than two? Because in two dimensions there are only two different places $j$ can be with the given distances, while in higher dimensions there's a whole continuum.

Comment: You may write equation of circles with centres at $p$ and $q$ with radiuses $qj$ and $pj$. $j$ is intersection of these.

Comment: It rather depends on if you know whether  $i$ and $j$ are on the same side of the line $pq$ or on opposite sides.

Comment: Are there any restrictions? There might not always be enough information. For example in the image you gave point $j$ could have been on the other side of line connecting $p$ and $q$ and you would have got the same information.